# Extract string list from a long string using prefix pattern in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string, parsing

I have a very big string with a lot of usernames. I want to extract the names from the string. That means I have one big string with lot of names in it. At the end I want every username in a string array.

An example of the string:

```
blablablabla@User;\u0004User\username,blablablablablablablabla@User;\u0004User\anotherusername,@Viewblablablablablablablabla
```

1. Search for: `u0004User\`
2. Save all charractes until `,` is found in the string array

*Pseudocode:*

```
string [] array = new string []{};
int i = 0;
foreach (var c in bigdata)
{
    if(c == "u0004User\")
    {
      array[i] = c.AllCharactersUntil(','); 
      i++;
      //AllCharactersUntil is a pseudo function
    }
}
```

Comment: If `bigdata` is a `string` then using a `foreach` will pull out each `char` and you will not be about to compare that `string`.

Comment: so I go through the string with a foreach and I store every single char? char1 = u char2 = 0 char3 =4 ? Until all things match together u0004User?

Comment: Why do I get a downvote ? I have code I said what I need. I just don't know how

Comment: You could go through and keep track of the previous characters, but it's better to use the `IndexOf` and `Substring` methods that I've illustrated in my answer.

Comment: Note in the future be careful about how you represent a string that contains escaped values.  Specifically you should have two backslashes after "User" to indicate that it's an escaped backslash making it more obvious that the "\u0004" is one Unicode character.

Comment: @juharr why do I have a -1 ?

Comment: Well down votes are suppose to be for when the question doesn't show any research effort or if it is considered unclear or not useful.  I cannot say which of those reason, or any other the down voters had, but if I had to guess it would be the ambiguity of whether  you're dealing with an Unicode character or not.  I actually gave you an up vote because I thought the 2 down votes were undeserved.

Comment: @juharr thank you very much. You are very friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.IndexOf` to find the index of "u0004User\" then again to find the following comma.  Then use `string.Substring` to get the name.  Keeping track of the current index and using it to tell `IndexOf` where to start searching from.

```
string bigdata =
    @"blablablabla@User;\u0004User\username,blablablablablablablabla@User;\u0004User\anotherusername,@Viewblablablablablablablabla";

string searchValue = @"u0004User\";
int index = 0;
List<string> names = new List<string>();
while (index < bigdata.Length)
{
    index = bigdata.IndexOf(searchValue, index);
    if (index == -1) break;
    int start = index + searchValue.Length;
    int end = bigdata.IndexOf(',', start);
    if (end == -1) break;
    names.Add(bigdata.Substring(start, end - start));
    index = end + 1;
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", names));
```

That will give you the following output

> username, anotherusername

**NOTE**

I've assumed that the "\u0004" values are those 6 characters and not a single unicode character.  If it is a unicode character then you need the following change

```
string searchValue = "\u0004User\\";
```

Comment: using [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) would be better to cut the his string in to peaces

Comment: Thank you so much theoretical the code is working. And it is working with parts of my real Data. But with the whole string. I think thisis another problem. I accept this answer because it works.

Comment: @WiiMaxx You could use `string.Split`, but you'd still have to do additional processing and you would want to split on "u0004User\" then do a substring at the first comma (or another split, but that one would be overkill IMO).

Comment: @FlorianNeiss Are the "\u0004" values a unicode character or actually those 6 characters?  I assumed it was the characters based on your code searching for just the "u0004".

Comment: @juharr actually it is EOT ␄ (Used on Unix to signal end-of-file condition on, or to logout from a terminal.)

Comment: @FlorianNeiss In that case see my note about what your `searchValue` should be.  I'm assuming that the backslash after "User" is an actual backslash and not the beginning of another escape character.

Comment: @juharr it is still not working with my real data just with a small part of it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94437/discussion-between-florian-neiss-and-juharr).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple result:

```
string input = "blablablabla@User;\\u0004User\username,blablablablablablablabla@User;\\u0004User\anotherusername,@Viewblablablablablablablabla";
List<string> userNames = new List<string>();
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"(u0004User\\)(.*?),", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
   {
     string currentUserName = match.Groups[2].ToString();        
     userNames.Add(currentUserName);    // Add UserName to List 
   }
```

Comment: But I need just the username with split i get stinrg1[blablablabla@User;\u0004User\username,blablablablablablablabla@User;\u0004User\anotherusername,] string2[@Viewblablablablablablablabla]

Comment: I improved the answer hope it is better for you now ...
It should atleast suit your needs.

Comment: It looks like the "\u0004" is actually a unicode character, so the pattern will need to be updated to "\u0004User\\\\.*?," and not a verbatim string.

Comment: well ... for me it worked fine in my VS ... u got the @ infront of it ?

Comment: @FeDe I mean that the OP has indicated that `input` actually contains Unicode characters.  So you'd have to remove the @ from your `input` and double up the backslashes after "User" to simulate the actual data.

Comment: just use regex groups and the whole remove(0,10) will be redundant and code cleaner, basically the nicest solution to this problem, just not necessarily fastest

Comment: now your solution should be the one accepted here :)

Comment: Not sure your change in the `input` is correct.  There should only be one backslash before the "u0004" so that it's a unicode character.  Then you'd need on backslash before the "u0004" in your pattern, remove the @ and double up the other backslashes.

Comment: Also why are you using `List<char[]>` instead of `List<string>`?

Comment: @juharr thought the queston was about char[] but basically its the same .. it doesn't really matter ..